# Why would this memory leak occur?

Tags: c, pointers

I've isolated a memory leak to these lines:

```
char* word_ptr;
while(read_word(fp, word)) {
    word_ptr = strdup(to_lower_case(word));
    // other stuff happens, loop closes properly, etc.
```

Since I don't malloc word_ptr, I don't need to free it. If you need the lowercase function, it is here:

```
char* to_lower_case(char *string) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
        string[i] = tolower(string[i]);
    }

    return string;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Since I don't malloc word_ptr ...

But `strdup()` allocates memory with `malloc()`, so it is all the same.

From `man 3 strdup`:

> Memory for the new string is obtained with `malloc(3)`, and can be freed with `free(3)`.

Comment: So do I have to free(word_ptr)?

Comment: @marchon: Yes, the same logic as with `malloc()`: check for `NULL` on failure, `free()` the memory... You can even `realloc()` the returned memory, if needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, freeing it doesn't make the error go away?

Comment: @marchon: Do you use `word_ptr` outside of the `while` loop?  If not, then you'd free `word_ptr` at the end of each loop iteration; otherwise, it would depend on how you're using `word_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

`strdup` does the `malloc` for you - see http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup